# Mail notifications in redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-email

I have one requirement.I want to send mail to the person(client) who raised the ticket when I create an new issues in redmine.I just want to send the ticket ID to the person(client)who raised the ticket..
Can anyone help me..
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can put the client email id in watchers in redmine while creating the issue and update that issue it will send an email to everyone related to that issue number.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I want to send individual mail only to the person who raised the ticket and not to everyone involved in that project..

Comment: There is a settings tab for emails in administration of redmine

Comment: my requirement is like..I will create a custom field with list format and it contains list of clients names or email id.If i click on particular client on that mail regarding the ticket number should be sent to that client .

Answer (score 0):

To send an email to a user custom field, you can use this redmine plugin: http://www.redmine.org/plugins/notify_custom_users

Comment: M getting error in running rake command.                                                   rake aborted!
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/home/administrator/redmine_2.5.1/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (111)